# Lookup for a word in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, lookup, vlookup, calculated-field

Is there any way to search for a word in Tableau, and returns the value next to the word, something the vlookup function in Excel. For example if i want to find a word "Pen" in the table and return the column next to it named Amount.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: @Dinesh.hmn ,i have a table in excel with a column with words named "Column 1" and 5 more columns with the sales with the respective years(2013,2014,2015,2016,2017. i would like to  do a calculated field in tableau which will be search the word for example , take the word as "A", in "column 1" and returns the value in  "year 2016". thanks